# How to get cpu/memory/network usage percentage in ASP.NET Core to do throttling?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, memory-management, cpu-usage

My web application is deployed in azure, which is implemented in Asp.Net Core. I want to throttle requests basing on cpu/memory/network usage percentage. For example, when the cpu usage is above 90%, the throttling component will throttle 50% of the requests.

The big question is:

- How to get cpu/memory/network usage percentage in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Could you please tell me which Azure service you have used to host your asp.net core application? Web app or VM?

Comment: It's a web app service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, azure WebApp is a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox), we don't have enough permission to access the Azure web app's worker server's metrics.

> The user account must either be a member of the Administrators group or a member of the Performance Monitor Users group in Windows.

Here is a workaround, we could enable the application Insight to do that. We need to configurate Application Insight for Azure WebApp. Details, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=net).

We could use Application Insight rest api to get the current web app's metrics like process cpu usage. [API Document](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference).

We could get the application id and api key in the Application Insight portal like below image shows:

Details, you could refer to this [article](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Authorization/API-key-and-App-ID).

[image]

Then you could use below codes to send request to Application Insight API to get current CPU usage.

```
    public static string GetTelemetry(string appid, string apikey)
    {

        string Url = "https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{0}/metrics/performanceCounters/processCpuPercentage";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", apikey);
        var req = string.Format(Url, appid);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(req).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        else
        {
            return response.ReasonPhrase;
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]